# Lyx Current Date Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: lyx, keyboard

I'm trying to create a keyboard shortcut to add date to my class notes in Lyx so that they are organized better. I want the shortcut to add the notes on the left.

That is, I just want to add the following, with the current date each time.

[image]

The  following keyboard shortcut does half the job:

```
command-sequence ert-insert; self-insert \reversemarginpar; char-forward; marginalnote-insert; self-insert 2017-05-07; char-forward
```

However, the date is not assigned dynamically. Is it possible to make the date be filled automatically based on current writing (not compiling) date?

Comment: Have you tried after the self-insert to simply put `\today`?

Comment: @GalGrünfeld This adds the day of compilation and not the day of adding the comment.

Comment: Untested idea: define a dummy 'converter' to call an external script that puts the date in a file, e.g., `currentdate.tex`, then in your keyboard shortcut call the converter and `self-insert \input{currentdate.tex}`.

Comment: @Marijn It will work only once, no? If I use the keyboard shortcut twice in a single document, then I'll get the same value in both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the LyX command `date-insert` instead of `self-insert`. It receives a parameter for the date format, in `strftime` format (e.g. `%Y-%m-%d`).

I.e., the full keyboard binding is:

```
command-sequence ert-insert; self-insert \reversemarginpar; char-forward; marginalnote-insert; date-insert; char-forward
```

All the commands appear in [LyX Wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyxFunctionList), but without much documentation. 
The [source code](http://www.lyx.org/trac/browser/lyxgit/src/LyXAction.cpp)  contains complete and thorough documentation, so it is easier to find the needed commands there.

As for possibility to use `self-insert` for dynamic input, by looking at the source, it seems that it only copies the text as is, as if it was inserted using keyboard.